# Advanced Custom Fields adding an Image with a "Choice" field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have an Image, that gives the photographer credit, that I would like to be able show depending on the Photograph. In ACF is there a way to set it up so that when I select a "Choice" field that the photo credit will show depending on the choice? And the Image has to link to the Photographers web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I ended up just using a true/false custom field with an if/else statement. Being it was only on one custom post type I just added the php in post type.

```
<?php if( get_field('image4') ) { echo "Photo's taken by: <a href='http://www.sample.com/'><img src='http://photolinkhere.jpg' /></a>"; } else{} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example. You can have four fields.

- Photo (Image field)
- Give Credit (True/False field)
- Photographer (Text)
- Photographer URL (Text)

To make Photographer and Photographer URL field dependent to Give Credit field, you need to enable `Conditional Logic` and set it to `Yes`. Under that set `Give Credit` - `is equal to` - `checked`. You can find this option in the bottom when you edit field.

Comment: That would work but wouldn't I have to upload the image every time? Id like it streamlined so id just have to say "True" and it would show.